# SSH connections from windows are aborted within a minute

Tags: windows, ssh

If I start an SSH connection with my windows 10 laptop, it gets aborted within a minute. Even when I'm actively using the connection.

I tried multiple servers (Ubuntu 18, 16 and ESXi 6.7) all with the same problem, also tried to use different clients (putty and mobaXterm).

Did a packet capture and it does look like the connected server sends a `RST` with `ACK` to my laptop. After which my laptop responds `FIN` with `ACK`.

If I setup the same connection from my phone with JuiceSSH it keeps working normally. That's why I suspect my laptop, but I have no idea how to resolve it.
Any ideas?

Comment: That also troubles me. I got 'Software causes connection abort' in mobaxterm within 0-5 minutes(only happened in EC2 instances) , but it works well while using ssh from command line.

Answer (score -1):

In putty feel free to try with:

```
In your session properties, go to Connection and under Sending of null packets 
to keep session active, set Seconds between keepalives (0 to turn off) to e.g. 
300 (5 minutes).
```

source: https://patrickmn.com/aside/how-to-keep-alive-ssh-sessions/

Comment: I not even making it to 5 minutes. That's why I tried to do it with 30 and even 3 seconds. Same issue.